# getLargePrime Java loop

Tags: java, loops

the below code if number were 90, I don't see why "i" would not be 90 or 10 nor 3, but stopped at 5.

Thanks in advance for help.

```
public class LargestPrime {

    public static int getLargestPrime(int number) {
        if (number <= 1) 
            return -1;
        for (int i = number ; i > 1; i--) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                number = i;
                System.out.println(" i= " + i + "  number= " + number);
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging, e.g., stepping through the logic (or just playing computer with pencil and paper)?

Comment: What is this code *supposed* to do? What are some inputs plus expected outputs?

Comment: return the largest prime number. If number is 90, it correctly returns 5 as the largest prime number. But as (number % i == 0), it should return at 90? or if the code should continue, why wouldn't it return 3.

Comment: can you provide more details to the question ? like some sample result on the inputs ?

Comment: You iterate until `i` is 1. It could only return at 90 if you had a `break` statement inside of the `if`. `i` stops at 1, not 5. If you put a println in an 'else' you'd see the other iterations on the console as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because at this point `i= 45  number= 45` everything is ok and we decrease `i` to 15, then 45 % 15 and again work fine `number % i == 0` and number become 15, but after this, your `i = 14, 13, 12 ...` it doesn't work because `15 % 14, 13, 12...` != 0.
Only when `i` becomes 5 it works again, because `15` (number) `% 5` (i) `== 0`. After that, the program stops to give out the `number`s and `i` because number becomes 5 and i goes from 4 to 1. So 5 % 4, 3, 2, 1 != 0.

Comment: Thank you so much Edwin.